# How to match [a-z] [a-z] [a-z] where those letters must be the same letter in any single match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Example in this string:

"a a b b b c b c c c a a a a c b c"

I'd like the regex to select.

b b b;

c c c;

a a a;

a a a;

I found out that I have to look ahead with (?= to match even the overlapping ones, the question is how to make the letters be the same in every individual match, instead of getting results like:

a a b;

a b b;

b b c;

and so on...

Comment: Use capturing group and backreference.

Comment: Can you use LINQ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the first letter and match the next two against it:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]) \1 \1/', $string, $matches);
```

- `([a-z])` match and capture a letter a-z
- match a space then `\1` matches the matched letter again
- match a space then `\1` matches the matched letter again

`/([a-z])( \1){2}/` will also work:

- `([a-z])` match and capture a letter a-z
- `( \1)` match a space then `\1` matches the matched letter again two times `{2}`

Comment: I'm testing it here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and this does not seem to give any results. Ok, strange it gives the results when I don't look ahead, but it doesn't if I look. I.e. This gives back results: ([a-z]) \1 \1 and this doesn't (?=(([a-z]) \1 \1))

Comment: Dunno, that's nothing like your question.

Comment: Anyways this is what I was asking for. I'll figure it out from here on. Thanks.

Comment: @cybera You made a second capture group there, https://regex101.com/r/rbz1P8/1. e.g. use `(?=(([a-z]) \2 \2))`. Every capture group gets its own backreference.